# Is it ok to use rdbuf()->in_avail() to check if things have been printed on stringstream

Tags: c++

In my code base there is code like the example below. A stringstream is used to collect output and later, if there have been things written to the stream these things are written to another stream. To check if there are things on the collecting stream the code uses `rdbuf()->in_avail()`. Is this well defined, and has the expected behavior changed between C++17 and C++20?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::stringstream ss;

  ss.str("");
  
  ss << "kalle tar kulan";

  if (ss.rdbuf()->in_avail())
    std::cout << ss.rdbuf() << "\n";
}
```

When compiling the with GCC-13, the code prints "kalle tar kulan" both in C++17 and C++20 mode. When compiling with MSVC 17.6 it does in in C++17 mode but not in C++20 mode.

Comment: in_avail only makes sense for *input* streams and it is absolutely not guaranteed to work as you want in any C++ version.

Comment: What is intended, can you describe that? Also please describe what not intended is in C++20 of MSVC.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI `std::stringstream` is both an input stream and an output stream. Maybe you thought the OP is using `std::ostringstream` (output only) instead?

Comment: @RemyLebeau even for input streams there is no guarantee that *everything* is available in `in_avail` anyway. Why not just use `ss.str()`?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI true, but it should tell that *something* is available, which is all the example needs.